# Upload files older than 180 days to SFTP server using WinSCP?

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

My requirement is that I want to upload all local files from Windows machine, which are older than **180 days**, to SFTP server by using a batch file. Relevant files in all subdirectories should be uploaded, recreating the local folder directory structure on the SFTP server.

Below are the commands which I have to tried by running on command prompt to upload the Windows Server files in SFTP server and it is running as expected 
as I do not have idea about how to use the time value (180 days) condition in commands so I have tried without time period condition, 
But I want to automate this process by creating a Batch file *(using WinSCP commands)* To Upload all files including sub-folders which are older than **180 days**.

```
@echo off

set USERNAME=myusername
set PASSWORD=mypassword
winscp.com /script=script.txt

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)
```

The `script.txt`:

```
open logsarchive@sftp.xxxx.com
cd /logsarchive
lcd D:\Logs\
lcd WEBSERVER1
cd WEBSERVER1
exit
```

Any examples/suggestions would appreciated.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: please check the updated question, thanks!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : Please check the updated question, Thanks for the quick response.!

Comment: sorry, actually I want to move the files only but it should also create the Local folder Directory to SFTP server _(after first time upload/creating the directory, I want to upload only the files to SFTP in a respective directories which are older than 180 days)_.Hope this clears the requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To upload files older than 180 days (while still reproducing a local directory structure on the server) use:

```
put * -filemask=<180D
```

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask